# How do I update and set all rows in current hour only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to only change the rows from the current hour on todays date.

```
// Have the current date
$date = "2019-03-21 17:14:03"; 
$rel = 8 // like an id.

$sql = "UPDATE graph SET code = '$code' WHERE myDate = '$date' AND rel = '$rel'";

if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function.

For example:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE graph SET code = '$code' WHERE myDate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)"
```

This will return all values where `myDate` is in the past hour.

Comment: This returns all records within the *last 60 minutes*, which is, by default, different than all records within the *current hour*...

Comment: @GMB I agree that the question is ambiguous.  This is simply the way I interpreted the question when I first read it.

Comment: yep, there was more than one way to interpret the question... At the end of the day, it seems like *you* had it right...

Answer (score 2):

Use `DATE_FORMAT` to compute the beginning of the current hour, and compare it against your datetime column. You don't need to pass the date as a parameter, you can get the current date/time with `NOW()`:

```
UPDATE graph SET code = :code
WHERE myDate >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:00:00') AND rel = :rel
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way by ultilising HOUR() function in MYSQL:

```
$sql = "UPDATE graph SET CODE = '$code' WHERE DATE(myDate) = '$date' AND HOUR(NOW()) = HOUR ('$date') AND rel = '$rel'"
```